# Smtp mail fails, when not run in local environment

Tags: heroku, smtp, strapi

I have a strapi cms application, setup to send mails with nodemailer.
It works on localhost, but when i deploy it to heroku it fails with "Error: Invalid
login".

Config:

```
email: {
  provider: 'nodemailer',
  providerOptions: {
    host: env('EMAIL_SERVER_HOST'),
    port: env('EMAIL_SERVER_PORT', 587),
    auth: {
      user: env('EMAIL_SERVER_USER'),
      pass: env('EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD'),
    },
  },
  settings: {
    defaultFrom: env('EMAIL_SERVER_USER'),
    defaultReplyTo: env('EMAIL_REPLY'),
  },
},
```

Error:

```
2021-08-04T16:11:33.384923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/email/contact" host=arbejdernesstemme-cms-stage.herokuapp.com request_id=31f0287e-6c1b-4cdd-b1ad-42e783f58fdd fwd="83.94.170.136" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6307ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374189+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-04T16:11:33.373Z] error Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [DB6PR0802CA0048.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com]
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374222+00:00 app[web.1]: at SMTPConnection._formatError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:774:19)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374223+00:00 app[web.1]: at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1513:34)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374223+00:00 app[web.1]: at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1471:18)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374223+00:00 app[web.1]: at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:932:20)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374224+00:00 app[web.1]: at SMTPConnection._onData (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:739:14)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374225+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:189:44)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374226+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374227+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374227+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374228+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.374228+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
2021-08-04T16:11:33.377697+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-04T16:11:33.377Z] debug POST /email/contact (6288 ms) 500
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Outlook `Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [DB6PR0802CA0048.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com]` and you are using port `587`

So, you will need to add the SSL and security configurations needed to access a secure port.

`secure: true`

Also, **try first accessing this account from an email client** to check credentials are working correctly.

What I can see from logs, **the problem is at the authentication level** with the mail server. Not really with Strapi.

```
email: {
  provider: 'nodemailer',
  providerOptions: {
    host: env('EMAIL_SERVER_HOST'),
    port: env('EMAIL_SERVER_PORT', 587),
                                          secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: env('EMAIL_SERVER_USER'),
      pass: env('EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD'),
    },
  },
  settings: {
    defaultFrom: env('EMAIL_SERVER_USER'),
    defaultReplyTo: env('EMAIL_REPLY'),
  },
},
```

[image]

Note: Also, if that doesn't work, try connecting to SMTP directly.
Ref: https://github.com/bass3l/strapi-provider-email-smtp

From that provider, you can have better control over the connection. i.e.

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  email: {
    provider: 'smtp',
    providerOptions: {
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com', //SMTP Host
      port: 465   , //SMTP Port
      secure: true,
      username: 'my.username@gmail.com',
      password: 'my.password',
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      requireTLS: true,
      connectionTimeout: 1,
    },
    settings: {
      from: 'my.username@gmail.com',
      replyTo: 'my.username@gmail.com',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with outlook, so i switched to gmail and it works fine

Comment: Because of the error you showed on the log, I am almost certain that it's a problem at Outlook level. That why I said, you should try to connect and send an email from a client first. i.e. Thunderbird, Windows Mail, Kmail etc.
So if that does work you know its Stapi configuration.